# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID - 80040154

Tags: dll, com, comexception

I Have a 3rd Party component "ArchestrA.MxAccess.dll" (which is build on x86 by corgflags)  with 2 type libraries and having development PC (XP SP2 32-bit) using Visual Studio 2008.

when I creating instance of a Class in the code, it throws COMException - 80040154.

Following Solutions I have tried:

1. RegSVR32 the DLL, but it can't be registered. as "Entry point not found".
2. Regtlib type libraries, succeed
3. regasm the DLL, succeed.
4. Compiler mode is on x86.
5. CLSID which is in error have entry in registry: HKCR\CLSID\ and pointing to 
   this DLL.

Please help. i am searching solution since 3 days.

Dev.

---

regasm with codebase makes entry with codebase and pointing to file name,It is succeed. have also registered dll using GACUtill, it is succeed.

but Same Error is coming.

my ProcMon can not found entries in

```
"HKCR\CLSID\{c30...}\"
<TreatAs>, <InprocServerX86>, <LocalServer32>, <APPID>
```

and same as in

```
"HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{C30..}\".
```

Only Available Entry is

```
1. {CLSID}\InProcServer\Default,Assembly,Class,codebase,RuntimeVersion

2. {CLSID}\InProcServer\2.0.0.0\Default,Assembly,Class,codebase,RuntimeVersion
```

runtimeVersion = V1.1.4322

is it means I need to install 1.1 framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers of  Tech support from WonderWare
is
There is need of deploying "System Platform".

so it is basic authentication(checking deployment of System Platform and its license) before initializing COM.

registering with GACUtil is helpful. COM is not registering itself sometimes.

Thanks Again.